# How to write unit test for directive link AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

Good day!

This is my first time writing a unit test and I don't even know where to begin. I have look through some example and here is my code.

This is a validation function located in my directive

```
scope.validateInput = function () {
     if (scope.description < 100) {
          scope.validate_description_message = true;
     }
}
```

Here is my unit test

```
describe('scope.validateInput', function() {
     beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $compile) {
            scope = $rootScope;
            element = angular.element(html);
            $compile(element)(scope);
            scope.$digest();
     }));

     it('should return true when scope.description is less than 100 characters.', inject(function() {
            $rootScope.description = 1;
            $rootScope.validateInput();
            expect($rootScope.validate_description_message).toEqual(true);
        }));
    });
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yeah I think it looks good, your question is not that clear or concrete though :)

Comment: when I run the test it returned 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating $rootScope,description = -1)

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your $scope inside the describe first. And create a new scope from the $rootscope.

```
describe('scope.validateInput', function() {
     var scope;
     beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $compile) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            element = angular.element(html);
            $compile(element)(scope);
            scope.$digest();
     }));

     it('should return true when scope.description is less than 100 characters.', inject(function() {
            scope.description = 1;
            scope.validateInput();
            expect(scope.validate_description_message).toEqual(true);
        }));
    });
```